# Hazelcast Connection for Oracle DB

Tags: java

How to connect Oracle DB through HAZEL-CAST? I need to retrieve oracle db through Hazel-cast instances? Please give any sample code for establish connection

Thanks Clark & Allaudeen,

I have used JDBC and getting record from table and moved to one of distributed data structures in Hazel cast. My requirement, if any thing i will modified or updated in distributed data structures and also will sync in db also. Can you suggest me

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Hazelcast is an in-memory Open Source data grid, you will need to use JDBC to connect to your database

Comment: Thanks Clark, I have used JDBC and getting record from table and moved to one of distributed data structures in Hazel cast. My requirement, if any thing i will modified or updated in distributed data structures and also will sync in db also. Can you suggest me

Comment: Thanks Allaudeen,  I have used JDBC and getting record from table and moved to one of distributed data structures in Hazel cast. My requirement, if any thing i will modified or updated in distributed data structures and also will sync in db also. Can you suggest me